# Migration from server hosting in a DC to Azure

Tags: azure, hosting, web-hosting, cloud-hosting, self-hosting

I run my own uk based hosting and web design company.

We have about 10 physical servers in a DC in the UK and host about 300 or so web sites, email servers and web applications. They are all on a windows server platform with a few linux VM's.

I now have a Windows Azure account, I have set up a medium windows 2008 server within my azure account and want to start using it to maybe host and migrate some of my web sites and services onto my azure account and new server. With the view that maybe I could move ALL my services over and get rid of the need for any of my physical servers in the DC.

My question that I am still really struggling with how much this will really cost me on an ongoing basis.

The billing area, doesnt really tell me much as it simply shows my bill as £0.00. It shows my usage but I am really struggling to compare the resources I am currently using compared to how its billed in azure? It doesnt even show me what it would have cost me if I werent ona trial.

I dont want to move web hosted sites over if its going to cost me more than hosting in my current DC.

I was thinking of moving many sites onto the new server i have set up as its a better spec than a few of my current servers, so would see a big benefit, I even considered setting up a much larger Server in my Azure account but again unsure as to the real cost of that box its hard to compare.

Do I simply need to look at the calculator and select the number of servers i wil deploy, select how much storage I need and bandwidth? Or do I need to look at the items in the billing area as well - such as:

Compute units,Storage Transactions,Data Transfer Out,Data Transfer In

When I set up the server it didnt ask me for how much storage I wanted it just set it up with about 150GB avaialble in the actual server.

Any advice as I really see this as something i want to use over the next 12 months, but not if once i have finally migrated stuff its going to cost me more than my normal hosting and i have to move stuff all back at the end of the 12 months.

Cheers

Comment: I think this question is better-suited to [serverfault](http://www.serverfault.com)

Answer (score 2):

Because you're using [Windows Azure Virtual Machines](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsazure/jj156003), you should first use the [virtual machine pricing calculator](https://www.windowsazure.com/en-us/pricing/calculator/?scenario=virtual-machines).  This calculator only displays the costs that are relevant for your scenario except for the storage transaction cost.  Here is a breakdown of the costs you'll have to consider:

### Virtual Machines

The Virtual Machine cost appears on the bill as compute units.  Throughout the Windows Azure Virtual Machine preview, the cost per core per hour is $0.08.  Once VMs reach general availability, the cost will be $0.115 per core per hour for Windows VMs and $0.085 for Linux VMs.  Using the calculator, you can see that a medium instance uses two cores and will therefore be billed at $0.16 per hour during the preview period.  You will have to use your best judgement to determine how many virtual machines you'll need and how large they should be.

### Storage

You will have to pay for the data actually used within your VHDs.  Let's assume you have one virtual machine with one VHD attached.  If the size of the VHD 200GB, but only 100GB is used, you will have to pay for 100GB per month.

### Bandwidth

Microsoft now only charges for egress data transfers (data going out of the data center).  With this pricing change, the Data Transfer In section of the billing area will always be 0.00.  Hopefully, you already have a good idea about your current outbound data usage.  If so, you can calculate your bandwidth cost by simply moving the bandwidth slider to the correct spot.

### Storage Transactions

If you scroll down to the Transactions section of [this blog post](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/windowsazure/archive/2012/06/28/data-series-exploring-windows-azure-drives-disks-and-images.aspx), you'll see how storage transactions are counted.  Basically, you count one transaction per write operation and possibly one transaction per read operation depending if the data is cached or not.  The cost of storage transactions are negligible because you only have to pay one cent per 100,000 transactions.  That's why storage transactions are left out of the calculator.

HTH

Answer (score 1):

To answer such question in an input box has limitation to express in details. The cost calculator is there to give you an estimate of upper limit about what the cost will be if your usage are under selected limit. Based on my personal experiences if you choose higher limits of usage and keep the usages within your forecast limits, there will be no hidden charges. But the reality could be far different because you may not estimate the usages correctly at first and this could change the cost later.

For moving a traditional web hosting solution to Windows Azure, latest release of Windows Azure Virtual Machine is best fit as this requires minimum migration complexity. So the VM size you will choose will have fixed resources (compute, local storage, network bandwidth, disk I/O etc) and the cost will be fixed as long as you are under limit so there will not be unseen charges.

Windows Azure Storage is pay as you go (ranges ~$0.012/GB depend on usage limit) and there is no limit. When moving from traditions web hosting to Cloud environment, due to application architecture design, I have seen less Cloud storage usage and more VM storage so it may not cost a lot.

The place you will see cost variation is data egress/ingress and it is difficult to forecast as it is all depend on application usage, so this is something you will have to account as variable cost.

You can also contact [Windows Azure Virtual Machine Forum](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/WAVirtualMachinesforLinux/threads) where dedicated Windows Azure Virtual Machine resources are available to answer your such questions.

Finally One thing I would also add that Windows Azure Virtual Machines are still in preview mode so it would be best to bring some of your business to Windows Azure VM as trial and testing purpose because now matter what you think you may encounter problems (because it is preview release) and this could case service disruption.